How to use for with commas, and, or in sentences

"Machines for the reception, conversion and transmission or regeneration of data."

What is the meaning of this sentence?

A. Machines for either reception, having both conversion and transmission, regeneration.
B. 1.Machines having all functions of reception, conversion, transmission.
     2.regeneration.
C. Machines having all functions of reception, convention, transmission or regeneration.


This phrase is certainly in need of some additional "grammatical formatting"; one possibility is "Machines either for the reception, conversion and transmission or for the regeneration of data.".  The reading would then be that of "B" with "1" and "2" being exclusive of one another.

What's the surrounding context?

This sentence has multiple possible meanings, and the question does not contain enough information to decide which is meant.

Other apparatus for transmission or reception of voice, images or other data, including apparatus for communication in a wired or wireless network (such as a local or wide area network) :Machines for the reception, conversion and
transmission or regeneration of voice, images or other data, including switching and routing apparatus :

It reads like a patent, which have their own conventions unrelated to English as it is normally used.

It's an ambiguous construction.
Here's an example where the plural noun "books" refers to different instances for each category:

Books for Medicine, Engineering, and Law can become heavy if not appropriately prepared.
-Guidelines to International Students in Canada

Here's an example where the plural noun "compact tractors" refers to multiple machines, each of which addresses all the categories listed:

compact tractors are great multi-purpose machines for homeowners, farmers, and businesses alike.
-Machine Finder

In your example, the wording given is ambiguous. You'll need to contact the manufacturer or inventor to find out whether each machine addresses one, some, or all the categories listed. The commas there don't carry enough discriminating power for this; neither do the conjunctions "and" and "or".
